# Manipulador de eventos para td?

Tags: jquery

Galera, primeiramente um bom dia.

Bom, eu gostaria de saber se é possível criar um manipulador para o caso de uma -td- ser modificada.

Exemplo. Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Olá</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Quando a td for modificada, ativar um manipulador de eventos. Tentei usar *.on('change')*, mas parece que funciona apenas para inputs, textarea, caixas de seleção...

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Grato desde já!

Comment: Não podes usar o código que modifica a tabela? Ela é alterada como?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Bom, estou tentando criar um script do Tampermonkey, que pega as informações de uma tabela. Eu precisaria de um manipulador de evento para caso ela seja modificada. Mas não sei o que fazer.

Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Mas, como uma tabela, que é uma estrutura "fixa", vai sofrer uma manipulação? Tabela exibe dados formatados, não é usada pra manipulação. Explique melhor o que pretende.

Comment: As informações dessa tabela são atualizadas dinamicamente quando se clica em um botão. Eu gostaria de pegar a segunda linha dessa tabela. Entende?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Talvez dê certo um jeito de ficar vendo o valor de tempos em tempos com um "timer". Daí se o valor for diferente do anterior, quer dizer que mudou, aí dispara a ação desejada.

Comment: Você não pode pegar as informações no mesmo processo que atualiza a tabela? Tipo, clica no botão, atualiza a tabela e envia os mesmos dados para onde você precisa?

Comment: Fleuquer, obrigado pela resposta.

Bom, não sou eu quem gerencio o sistema ao qual estou fazendo um script, entende?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Rodrigo, obrigado pela resposta.

Você fala de usar setInterval() para isso?

A ideia parece ser boa. Vou tentar aqui.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha, pra manipular esse tipo de elemento, recomendo você usar a função `bind` do [jquery](https://jquery.com/) no elemento modificado.

Quando o elemento for modificado, você consegue chamar um `callback` para fazer o que você quiser após aquele elemento for modificado.
Exemplo:

```
$('td').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
  alert('changed');
});
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div

Comment: Muito obrigado Diego. Solucionou meu problema.

Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado! 
Boa sorte com o projeto! ;)